# Can't select folder in document picker in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

I followed this instruction https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories how to open UIDocumentPickerViewController.

```
// Create a document picker for directories.
let documentPicker =
    UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeFolder as String],
                                   in: .open)

documentPicker.delegate = self
    
// Present the document picker.
present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But for some reason user cannot select a folder on ios 12 and later. For ios 13 it works perfectly fine. I tried to search google for the answer but all the solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: Initial directory is available only for iOS13 or later

Comment: Anyway, forget this line, it's not the reason here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found out that picking a folder in iOS 12 and later is NOT AVAILABLE. It became available only since iOS 13, it was discussed in one of WWDC sessions.

> New in iOS 13, your app can present a UIDocumentPickerViewController
> to let the user pick a folder. -https://asciiwwdc.com/2019/sessions/719

So, I would recommend to try to use other solutions. For example, in my case I needed user to pick the folder to save some document there. But I found out that UIActivityViewController even suits my needs better.